# How to use nn.TransTransformerEncoder from pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am trying to use PyTorch's '''nn.TransformerEncoder''' module for a classification task.
I have data points of varying lengths i.e I have sequences of different lengths. All sequences have one corresponding output(target which is either 0 or 1).`[![enter code here][1]][1]`

This image outlines my dataset

This image shows how the sequences vary in length
[image]

However the entries of each sequence are of the same length.

I want to use this dataset to train an encoder part of the Transformer to be able to predict the corresponding outputs.
How can I go about doing this? And are there any examples I can check online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how your data actually looks like and what kind of output you expect. In general I would suggest to you to use the Transformers Library from HuggingFace, they have a lot of documentation and detailed code examples that you can work on -- plus an active forum. Here is a link to their description of [Encoder-Decoder Models](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/encoderdecoder). I hope that helps you a bit.

Comment: Does it make sense to train a non Text data on a model that was pre-trained in Text? I see almost all the models are pre-trained on text.

Comment: Likely not, you're right, I think you would need to train the model from scratch. Transformers are often about language, so most of what you will find concerns how to train new language models. But as your input data is sequential, you can formulate it as a language task. [Here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/char_rnn_classification_tutorial.html) is a rather lengthy tutorial from PyTroch using an RNN for character classification, which might help.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense now. I will definitely look into it.